# How to remove with awk/sed the characters that show up as SUB in Notepad++

Tags: awk, sed, notepad++

I have a file which when opened in Notepad++ contains some characters that display as `SUB`. I can remove those by simply doing a find&replace in Notepad++.

Is there a way to do the same thing using awk or sed?

EDIT: as per @konsolebox's suggestion I am adding a hexdump of the line:

```
00000000  35 38 32 37 7e 45 44 20  1a 6c 65 63 0a           |5827~ED .lec.|
```

The offending character was `1a`.

Comment: Yes but you'd need to tell us which characters `Notepad++` decides to display as `SUB`.

Comment: @EdMorton: how can i find out?

Comment: Read the `Notepad++` man page? Alternatively, assuming `Notepad++` is some kind of text editor, open your file in that and also open it in some other text editor (or in UNIX use `cat -v`) and see the difference.

Comment: @EdMorton: `cat -v` displays those characters as `^Z`.

Comment: OK, then theyre control-Zs and are easily removed. I'll post an answer.

Comment: @mitchus Try to post `hexdump -C < sample.txt`. `sample.txt` need not to have many contents. Just that SUB character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's CTRL-Z (0x1A), then you can have:

```
sed 's|\x1a||g' your_file.txt
```

Or in-place

```
sed -i 's|\x1a||g' your_file.txt
```

Or use `tr`:

```
tr -d '\032' your_file.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sed 's/^Z//g' file
```

where `^Z` represents the Control-Z character you get when you hold down the `ctrl` and `z` keys simultaneously. You may need to type a Control-V before the Control-Z to disable any action it initiates.

```
$ cat -v file
a^Zb
$
$ sed 's/^Z//g' file | cat -v
ab
$
$ sed 's/[[:cntrl:]]//g' file | cat -v
ab
```

That last one will remove all control characters.